# preg_match_all matches array

Tags: php, regex

I have something like this

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/(`.+`)(\s+AS\s+`.+`)?/i', '`foo` AS `bar`', $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The result is

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => `foo` AS `bar`
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => `foo` AS `bar`
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

)
```

So, the question is why I don't have ' AS `bar`' in `$matches[2][0]`?
(If I remove the '?' symbol from regex, I'll get it, but I need the '?' :))

Comment: You can just add 'U' to the pattern modifiers (at the end with 'i'), it seems you're assuming every quantifier is non-greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantifiers like `+` are greedy by default so if the first one can match everything it will do so. Making it non-greedy should do the job:

```
preg_match_all('/(`.+?`)(\s+AS\s+`.+`)?/i', '`foo` AS `bar`', $matches);
```

And by the way, `$matches = array();` is not necessary - the variable is only written to by `preg_match_all` so it does not need to be initialized/defined before.

```
php > preg_match_all('/(`.+?`)(\s+AS\s+`.+`)?/i', '`foo` AS `bar`', $matches);
php > print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => `foo` AS `bar`
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => `foo`
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  AS `bar`
        )

)
```

Comment: Damn.. you beat me to it :-) Good and thorough explanation btw.